# Cannot see my LWC global action in my custom app in app manager

Tags: lightning-web-components, global-actions

I have created a aura component to call my LWC but it's not appearing when I go to my app through app manager.  Through my app manager, clicking on my test page, at the bottom right hand corner, clicking on Actions, I only see the standard actions, LOG CALL, NEW ACCCOUNT, NEW CASE,etc..

Here is my code

**createUser.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction">
    <c:createUserLWC />
</aura:component>
```

**createUserLWC.html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Hello" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <lightning-button name="hello" label="hello" onclick={sayHello}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**createUserLWC.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class CreateUserLWC extends LightningElement {
    sayHello() {
        alert('HELLO');
    }
}
```

**createUserLWC.js-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Best Component Ever</masterLabel>
    <description>This is a demo component.</description>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

---

Any advice on how to get my button up on my flexipage would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, in the builder, there's a refresh button (two arrows pointing at each other) that can reload the available list.

Comment: On the left hand side, I can see through the app manager, my LWC component.  The problem is that I don't see it in the "Actions" list.  I closed my browser and reloaded the app in a new browser and it didn't show up either.  It's just not there.

Comment: My Global action is called testuser, I don't see it.  See screenshot:   https://prnt.sc/s3lgot

Comment: You can find the source here  https://github.com/ronyaoun/globalaction

Answer (score -1):

The first thing you should check is weather you had created a global action of type Lightning Component or not.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's what I have.  Choosing Lightning Component is the only way I can add  my aura component.